# Replace a string with blanks

Tags: perl

I need to replace a certain string with a string blanks that equal removed lines, For instance If I am given

```
1234567890
```

I need to replace some of the text with blanks that equals the number of letters removed.

```
123    8790
```

or

```
1234    90
```

Comment: Missing infos: for shell ? dos ? perl ? python ???

Comment: number of letted removed ? are you passing a value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how the *"some of the text"* is specified.

Suppose you want to replace the string `4567` then you can use a pattern match to find and replace it, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

my $s = '1234567890';

$s =~ s/(4567)/' ' x length $1/e;
```

or if you know the offset and length of the substring then you can just use `substr`, like this

```
substr($s, 3, 4) = ' ' x 4;
```

which gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
#!/usr/perl
my $a="123456";
my $remove = "234";
$a=~ s/(.*)$remove(.*)/${1}.' ' x length($remove).${2}/e;
print $a;
```

Comment: It's very awkward capturing and copying back the start and end of the string. There's also no need for the braces around `1` and `2`. It will work fine as `$a =~ s/($remove)/' ' x length($1)/e`

Comment: true, it's a habit as I often replace 1s and 2s and $11 would translate as the 11th match, hence I always use ${1}.